# Sabre SOAP - wsse:Security - Not Bound

Tags: soap, sabre

I am trying to make a TOken request to the SABRE SOAP, I am using their examples but at the end I get this error:

```
  <faultstring>Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line 19 of document  : The prefix "wsse" for element "wsse:Security" is not bound. Nested exception: The prefix "wsse" for element "wsse:Security" is not bound.</faultstring>
```

This is my request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:web="http://webservices.sabre.com">
   <soapenv:Header>     
      <mes:MessageHeader mes:version="1">
         <mes:From>           
            <mes:PartyId>Client</mes:PartyId>           
         </mes:From>
         <mes:To>           
            <mes:PartyId>SWS</mes:PartyId>            
         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>DCG</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>123</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Service>Session</mes:Service>
         <mes:Action>TokenCreateRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>1234</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>2015-01-01T00:00:00</mes:Timestamp>           
         </mes:MessageData>       
      </mes:MessageHeader>
         <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>PCC</Organization>
                <Domain>DOMAIN</Domain>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:TokenCreateRQ Version="1.0.0"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is the WSDL file: http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/TokenCreateRQ.wsdl

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this structure. The difference are namespaces under Security.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>${#TestCase#Username}</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>${#TestCase#Password}</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>${#TestCase#CPAId}</Organization>
            <Domain>${#TestCase#Domain}</Domain>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
```

Comment: please take a look into the post by @Wisdoom. It looks more correct.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the namespace declaration, used declared as `sec` but then used `wsse`.

Replace: `xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"` 
With: `xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"`

As a simple recommendation for looking into namespaces, you can import the WSDL into SoapUI and check the blank example auto-generated with all the possible elements for the request.